# python - Multi-Objective optimization with multiple variables using DEAP

Tags: python, optimization, deap

I am trying to optimize two outputs of simulation software (I used random forest to train a model for fast prediction of outputs). There are seven input variables three are continuous, and the rest are discrete. I have used DEAP package for multi-objective optimization but only one variable or a set of related variables (something like knapsack). The mentioned seven variables are:

```
    n_rate = [0.1:0.5]
    estim = [1000, 1500, 2000]
    max_d = [1:20]
    ft = [None, "rel"]
    min_s = [2:1000]
    min_m = [1:1000]
    lim = [0:1]
```

Except `ft`, for all continues variables, it is possible to define several discrete numbers.

My question is how I can create different individuals for these inputs to define the population?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way that you do this is by registering "attributes" that each individual can be created from. Here is what I use in my code:

```
toolbox.register("attr_peak", random.uniform, 0.1,0.5)
toolbox.register("attr_hours", random.randint, 1, 15)
toolbox.register("attr_float", random.uniform, -8, 8)

toolbox.register("individual", tools.initCycle, creator.Individual,
                 (toolbox.attr_float,toolbox.attr_float,toolbox.attr_float,
                  toolbox.attr_hours,
                  toolbox.attr_float, toolbox.attr_float, toolbox.attr_float,
                  toolbox.attr_hours,toolbox.attr_peak
                  ), n=1)
```

In my code, I have three different "genes" or "attributes" as I have them registered in `toolbox`. In my example, I have two continuous variables and one integer constrained variable. For your example, this is how you would define your attributes:

```
toolbox.register("n_rate", random.uniform, 0.1, 0.5)
toolbox.register("estim", random.choice, [1000,1500,2000])
toolbox.register("max_d", random.randint, 1, 20)
toolbox.register("ft", random.choice, [None, 'rel'])
toolbox.register("min_m", random.randint, 1, 1000)
toolbox.register("min_s", random.randint, 2, 1000)
toolbox.register("lim", random.randint, 0, 1)
```

Then you would construct your individual similarly to how I have with `initCycle`.

```
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initCycle, creator.Individual, (toolbox.your_attribute, toolbox.next_attribute, ... ), n=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Given that we are at this point, what mutation mechanism should be used for such cases? cxOrdered seems to not be able to work and gives me an error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I believe that I wrote a custom mutation function to achieve my mutation. It took the mutation probabilities as arguments and then iterated through the individual, each time generating a random number and checking if it was below the mutation probability. While iterating through the individual, I set up if statements that applied different mutation schemes on each different attribute. If I wanted a random integer/decimal for one attribute, random choice for another, this can be achieved. I believe that DEAP has examples on custom functions. Will check my code and edit my answer tonight.